# Photos are not displayed on the page after deployment to github pages

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, github, vite

Photos are not displayed on the page after deployment to github pages.
The id is used to render the elements in the sheet with parameters. Data for parameters in json file.
One of these parameters is src and srcset. I tried the direct path from the folder, and uploaded it to the cloud and left links, but the image did not pull up. I understand that I am doing something wrong, but I don’t understand what.

link to repo
https://github.com/bukreiev/webstudio-project

I need the photos to be displayed after deployment

Comment: Sorry, you want someone to trawl through your 43 files, 2796 lines to find where you are *doing something wrong™*

Comment: Do you mean your [portfolio page](https://bukreiev.github.io/webstudio-project/portfolio)? I can see that you used Google Drive's link in the image source and there are lots of 403 Forbidden messages in the console window.